# can i search in list with Dynamic LINQ parser

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, dynamic-programming

in code page https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355513/Invent-your-own-Dynamic-LINQ-parser
first read above page
i want search in list in list

```cs
var item2 = new List<List<object>>()
    {
        new List<object>{"a", 1000 },
        new List<object>{"n", 900, 1000},
    };

string s = "[0] == \"a\" ";
```

but dont work
please help me
my variable is not constant
condition is dynamic and create from end user and maybe have `(&& || == >= != and .....)`

```cs
var pred = SimpleExpression.PredicateParser<Element>.Parse(s);
```

this line error in our code

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var item2 = new List<List<object>>()
           {
              new List<object>{"a", 1000 },
        new List<object>{"n", 900 ,1000},
   };

foreach(List<object> list in item2)
{
    foreach(object obj in list)
    {
        if(obj == "a")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("find!");
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: condition is dynamic and user create from console and maybe have( and or >= <= )your answere dont work i dont know condition

Answer (score 0):

Not direct answer to your quetion, but you can use well known [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamic-linq.net/)

```cs
var item2 = new List<List<object>>()
{
    new List<object>{"a", 1000 },
    new List<object>{"n", 900, 1000},
};

string s = "x => x[0] == \"a\" ";

var result = item2.AsQueryable().Where(s).ToList();
```

You can try it in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Il4MY5)

Comment: don't work because exist error in where(s) can not convert s to func

Comment: What do not work? You have my working example and working fiddle.